# Select different columns in different rows according to another pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic, data-science

I have a pandas Series which contains the column names that I need to collect data from:

```
1         col1
3         col4
4         col3
5         col5
6         col5
```

And the dataframe that contains data looks like:

```
   col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1  data1   data2   data3   data4   data5
3  data6   data7   data8   data9   data10
4  data11  data12  data13  data14  data15
5  data16  data17  data18  data19  data20
6  data21  data22  data23  data24  data25
```

The result should be like:

```
1 data1
3 data9
4 data13
5 data20
6 data25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
print (df2.lookup(df2.index, df1))

['data1' 'data9' 'data13' 'data20' 'data25']
```